# What is dev-fuse.device and why does it extend boot time?

Tags: boot, startup, services, device-name

Trying to see if I could speed up my system boot I ran `systemd-analyze plot > bootplot.svg`  [image].  Everything seems normal except for `dev-fuse.device` that starts at 7.7 sec and then shows as activating until the entire boot process completes at 24.1 sec. Everything else is shown as active after 10.3 sec (when the various network related services are activated) until the last services related to the graphical desktop start.  I've tried googling `dev-fuse.device``` but have come up with nothing.

What is `dev-fuse.device`?  Why does it take so long to activate?

The output from the following commands that may provide necessary info is at
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/53pBp43jMH/

```
cat /proc/version
cat /etc/*-release
cat /proc/cpuinfo
cat /etc/fstab
free -m
sudo blkid
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lshw -C memory 
sysctl vm.swappiness
sudo smartctl -a -d ata /dev/sda
sudo smartctl -a -d ata /dev/sdb
systemd-analyze blame
df
```

Swap appears to be configured correctly and all the disk UUIDs in `/etc/fstab` match up with the info from `sudo blkid` and `sudo lsblk -f`. The machine dates from 2012 so I'm running in Legacy mode rather than EFI. Running `systemd-analyze blame | grep "dev"` doesn't find an entry for `dev-fuse.device`.